# Searching complex array for and modifying a value in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a complex multi-dimensional array that looks something like

```
[name] => Marko Polo
[description] => New application
[number] => ABCD1234
[loans] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 123
                [application_id] => 456
                [loan_fees] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [loan_parts] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 987
                                [loan_id] => 123
                                [product_id] => 49788
                                [product] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 49788
                                        [lender] => MAC

...
```

I need to create an efficient way of traversing this array and, for example having a set of rules to filter/modify the data.

For example, in the array there is `[lender] => MAC`, I want to have something like

```
loans.loan_parts.product.lender.MAC = 'Macquarie'
```

This would be in a config of sorts such that if the data array changed, it would be simply a matter of changing that dot notation to point to the new location of the `lender` value.

Using this, I need to filter the `lender` and modify it to be `Macquarie` instead of `Mac`.

I know that a big no-no these days is using too many foreach loops and I've looked into Collections, but because the inner arrays are not named, I don't believe Collections is possible.

As I say, I'd like to avoid the situation of

```
foreach
    foreach
        if (is_array())
            foreach
```

eeewww!

How can I execute this in the most efficient manner due to the possible large size of the array and its complexity.

Comment: I think recursion will help you out =)

Comment: but if you have pre-defined structure of array, you can search at specific keys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk-recursive.php) with callback that will change behavior according to key of array.

```
<?php
//can pass variable by reference to change array in function
function handleMAC(&$item, $key)
{
    if($key == 'lender'){
      $item['MAC'] = 'your value';
    }
}

array_walk_recursive($array, 'handleMAC');
?>
```

Comment: array_walk is great, but the problem i'm having now is the original $array value is not being changed to `your_value`.  How do i change `$item['MAC']` to be something like `$array[][][]`

Comment: actually this is good - i use `&$item` and return the `$array`